# How could you solve a problem with dynamic in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I am trying to do dynamic imports through a json:

```
const data =[{
      id: 1,
      type: "Comp1",
      dir: "component",
      props: {
        children: "component 1",
        style: { color: "red", textAlign: "center" },
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: "Comp2",
      dir: "component",
      props: {
        children: "component 2 ",
        style: { color: "blue", textAlign: "center" },
      },
    }]

 const Custom = (data) => {
const type = data.type;
const X = dynamic(() => import(`@mui/material/${type}`));

return (
  <X severity="success">
    Here is a gentle confirmation that your action was successful.
  </X>
);
}
```

That code shows me an error that says the following: module not found, but when I stop using a variable in the import it works:

```
const X = dynamic(() => import(`@mui/material/Alert`));
```

When I place that line without the variable, it works as it should.

My question is the following: how can I correct this implementation so that it does not have errors and works as it should?
I appreciate a guide, I have tried many things but this is the one that gives me the least errors. i am using Nextjs App Router